# Community wiki answers are listing in the tag's hot tab, that mismatching with the description in the same page

Tags: support, community-wiki, hot-tab

When viewing any [tag's hot tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/messages/hot), I can see a description as below in the bottom of the page:

> Only top voted, non community-wiki answers of a minimum length are eligible

But I can see some of the community wiki answers too in the list.

> [image: "community wiki" in the "hot" tab]

So is this a bug or I'm missing anything?